# Why can't I capture with my webcam more than once with OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, file, opencv, image-processing, webcam

I tried to write a small Python program which would allow me to start the webcam and capture and save the image to a .png file:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
for i in range(3):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cap.release()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imwrite(str(i) + 'image.png', frame)
    else:
        print("Webcam not working")
        print(ret)
```

but when I execute it it would only save the image once under `0image.png` and then display this in the console:

```
Webcam not working
False
Webcam not working
False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because you explicitly `release` it right after reading the first frame.

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you, I moved the cap.release() outside of the loop and placed it at the end and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The cap.release() functions helps you to free up your system , i.e. , the camera device resource, and if not done so , then it will raise errors like Device or resource busy if you try to create a new instance .
So , you need to remove the cap.release() from your loop and place it at the end of your program .
This should work .

```html
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
for i in range(3):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imwrite(str(i) + 'image.png', frame)
    else:
        print("Webcam not working")
        print(ret)`
cap.release()
```